# How did Odin and Dr Strange know each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

Dr. Strange told Thor in *Thor: Ragnarok* that Odin doesn't want anyone to disturb him.

> **Thor**: If you knew where he was,
>   why didn't you call me?
>
> **Strange**: I have to tell you, he was adamant
>   that he not be disturbed. Your father said he had chosen
>   to remain in exile.

How does Odin know Strange so well that he trusts Strange more than his sons?

Answer (score 3):

How and When precisely, is unknown but we can make some reasonable assumptions between *The Dark World* and *Ragnarok*.

Loki hid Odin on Earth (at the the Shady Acres care home) until such time as Odin was able to free himself of Loki's spell.

Obviously, Odin, realising that his time was coming to an end decided to remain on Earth so it seems logical that Dr Strange would ask his intentions.

As for not trusting his sons, I'm not sure that was a factor. *Shame* perhaps since Hela is about to be released and Odin has gone to great lengths to ensure that no-one knows about her.

Comment: Strange said something about he helped odin to settle on earth